# Cannot invoke 'init' with argument of type 'NSNumber' (Swift)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, int, xcode6

I am trying to use 'weights' array to fill a graph with the below fetch request. But I am getting the error "Cannot invoke 'init' with argument of type 'NSNumber' and I have no idea why. 'weights' array should be an array of UInt16.

```
var weights : [Int16] = []


func weightFetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest {
            let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
            let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!
            let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Assessment")
            fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "nsDateOfAssessment", ascending: true)]
            var error: NSError?

            let fetchedResults = managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error) as [Assessment]?

            if let assessments = fetchedResults {
                let weightss = assessments.map { assessment in assessment.weight }

                weights = weightss

                println(weights)
                println(weightss)
            }
            return fetchRequest
        }

func lineChartView(lineChartView: JBLineChartView!, verticalValueForHorizontalIndex horizontalIndex: UInt, atLineIndex lineIndex: UInt) -> CGFloat {
        if (lineIndex == 0) {
            return CGFloat(weights[Int16(horizontalIndex)] as NSNumber) //Error here
        }
        return 0
    }
```

Comment: Why are you truncating horizontalIndex to an Int16, and why are you casting the weight value to an NSNumber? CGFloat initializer can't take an NSNumber, it should take a base numeric type.

Comment: @MattBridges: Actually CGFloat *can* be initialized with an NSNumber. But it is not necessary here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems in the line

```
return CGFloat(weights[Int16(horizontalIndex)] as NSNumber)
```

- `weights[Int16(horizontalIndex)]` does not compile because an `Int16`
  cannot be an array subscript. It should be `weights[Int(horizontalIndex)]`.
- `weights[...] as NSNumber` does not compile because there is no automatic bridging between the *fixed-size* integer types and `NSNumber`,
  it should be `NSNumber(short: weights[...])`.

So this would compile and work:

```
return CGFloat(NSNumber(short: weights[Int(horizontalIndex)]))
```

However, there is no need to use `NSNumber` in between, it can be
simplified to

```
return CGFloat(weights[Int(horizontalIndex)])
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm new at this so this stuff is all only starting to make sense to me. :)